# openpyxl write multiple rows in Excel

Tags: python, loops, openpyxl

I am trying to write multiple rows to Excel. "Containers" has an index/len of 10. Although I loop through it, I only get one row when I run the script.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
# define first empty row
start_row = sheet.max_row + 1

#write to excel
for container in containers:
 #Company name
 company_container = container.div.h2
 company = company_container.text.strip()

 #City
 city = container.div.a["title"]

 #URL
 url = container.div.div.a["href"]

 #Title
 title_container = container.findAll("div", {"class":"info"})
 title = title_container[0].img["alt"]

 #Description
 description = title_container[0].p.text

 #Programming language
 hardskill = "Java"

 #Vervolgactie (Teamleader)
 vervolgactie = "Nieuw"

 companyinfo = [company, city, url, title, description, hardskill, vervolgactie]

 for i in range(0,len(companyinfo)):
   e=sheet.cell(row=start_row,column=1+i)
   e.value=companyinfo[i]

wb.save("vacatures.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're writing everything out with `e=sheet.cell(row=start_row,column=1+i)` on the same row.

since everything in enclosed in the loop `for container in containers`, i'd just increment `start_row`after the sub loop.

```
 for i in range(0,len(companyinfo)):
   e=sheet.cell(row=start_row,column=1+i)
   e.value=companyinfo[i]

 start_row +=1 #not part of the above loop but part of the overarching loop
```

Another route i'd consider is to rename `start_row` to just row (this is more semantically clear) and have `row` defined in the loop

```
#start_row = sheet.max_row + 1

#write to excel
for container in containers:
 #row for this data to go on. 
 row = sheet.max_row + 1

 #Company name
 company_container = container.div.h2
 company = company_container.text.strip()
```